# worst case analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, pseudocode

Im learning worst case analysis of algorithm

For x>=2, and rand(x) is function that return 1 value from 1 to x-1 which have uniform probability $\frac{1}{x-1 }$ And max(x,y) output bigger value and min(x,y) output smaller value
I need to find the worst case complexity of each algorithm

```
Algorithm A
Input=n
x=n
WHILE x>=2
  y=rand(x)
  x=max(y,x-y)

ALGORITHM B
Input =n
x=n
While x>=2
  y=rand(x)
  X=min(y,x-y)

ALGORITHM C
  Input : value n (integer)
  void fn(x :int)
     if(x>=2)
       y=rand(x)
       Fn(y)
       Fn(x-y)
     Else 
     Return 
  fn(n)
```

For algorithm A , when x=10, suppose rand() return 1 , then max(1,x-1) so worst case will be O(n)

For algorithm B, when x =10 , suppose rand() return 4 from 10 , it will call min(4,10-4) , will call again  x=4 etc but worst case will be x/2 or (x-1)/2

For algorithm C

It is recursive(?) , for example if x =10 and y=rand(x)=4 , when it call Fn(4) and Fn(10-4=6) , it will cal again and again until smaller than 2 
But how can i find order of the worst case?

Comment: Are `x` and `X` supposed to be the same variable, or different? And the indentation seems wrong here. Even so, talking about the time complexity of algorithms which terminate randomly is quite strange; do you mean the expected running time? The "worst case" is unbounded.

Comment: @kaya3  yes x and X should be the same, yes running time for worst case

Comment: Well, either the worst case is infinity because the algorithm might never terminate, or there is no worst case because whenever it terminates, it isn't "worst" because another case could have taken more time.

Comment: @kaya3  it should terminate when x<2 , its okay if its not worst case though just i need to find the running time and what order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm A: The worst case happens when X decreases as slowly as possible. The largest possible value of X after one iteration of the loop body is X - 1 (since that's the maximum value rand can return, and since Y is positive then X - Y must be less than X). Therefore, in the worst case where rand always selects X - 1, the function has runtime that is asymptotically bounded by a linear function - O(n).

Algorithm B: The worst case happens when X decreases as slowly as possible. The largest possible value of X after one iteration of the loop body is floor(X / 2). The reason for this is the following: assume Y is less than floor(X / 2). Then min will select Y and not X - Y. Assume instead that Y is greater than floor(X / 2). Then min will select X - Y and not Y. Therefore, the worst case is achieved when Y = floor(X / 2). If we let N = 2^M, then X will be halved around M times. This means the runtime is asymptotically logarithmic - O(log n).

Algorithm C: We can write the recurrence relation for the runtime down as follows:

```
T(0) = a
T(1) = b
T(n) = T(f(n)) + T(n-f(n)) + c
```

We need to find the function f(n) which makes the recurrence as bad as possible. Let us start examining n = 2, 3, …, k, … and see if any patterns emerge which can inform us as to the right selection of the first few values of f(n):

```
T(2) has only one split: Y=1, X-Y=1; so T(2) = 2a + c
T(3) has two equivalent splits: Y=1, X-Y=2; so T(3) = 3a + 2c
T(4) has two different splits:
    Y=1, X-Y=3: 4a + 3c
    Y=2, X-Y=2: 4a + 3c
    these end up being the same
T(5) has two different splits:
    Y=1, X-Y=4: 5a + 4c
    Y=2, X-Y=3: 5a + 4c
    these end up being the same
T(6) has three different splits:
    Y=1, X-Y=5: 6a + 5c
    Y=2, X-Y=4: 6a + 5c
    Y=3, X-Y=3: 6a + 5c
    these end up being the same
```

These all turn out to be exactly the same; the choice among them appears not to matter at all. This may be due to the fact that the extra work at each step is constant; if it depended on n then the analysis may well have turned out differently. The expression for each of the values of n we looked at was of the form an + c(n-1). This is a linear function, so we expect the runtime of this algorithm to be asymptotically linear: O(n).

Comment: Thankyou so much for detailed explanation. For the last one, is recursive usually require order of n? If it depend on n , When is the function require order n/log n? And also for order n^2 or  n log n , is it usually inside two for loop?

Comment: @devss Check out the Master Theorem. The complexity of recursive functions like this is determined by the number of subproblems, the size of subproblems, and the amount of nonrecursive work done at each step. That we got O(n) here was caused by the facts that the sum of the size of subproblems is the same as the original problem along with a constant amount of work per step.